# Codename One CSS Box-Shadow not Rendering

Tags: css, codenameone, box-shadow

I have an Android application that uses CSS style-sheet.

I am styling a button according to the manual [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html), but I can't seem to get it working  properly.

This is my code from the theme.css file:

```
Button {
    background-color: #73258d;
    margin: 25pt;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4pt; 
    cn1-box-shadow-color: green;
    cn1-box-shadow-spread: 4mm;
    padding: 10pt;
}
```

The spread is showing correctly, but the green shadow color is not rendering at all. I don't have any shadow color whatsoever.

Theses are the screenshots from mt res file .....

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this code example can help: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rounded-corners-shadows-and-gradients-with-css.html#_outer_shadows

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani , I have used the approach you mention before, but it seems that the one I am trying out is, for some reason, more indicated. At least it is elegant and I would like to figure out, why it is not working as expected. Thanks for your effort, nevertheless it is helpful  ....

Comment: Do you have enough padding for the border to render. Notice that if the pressed button has different padding from the regular button this won't work great as the UI would need to "jump".

Comment: @Shai, I have applied the CSS settings to an unpressed button  and added some padding. Kindly see the updated code above. There is still no drop-shadow color visible.

Comment: Can you open the res file and look at the generated theme?
Was it generated via images or via shadow, is the shadow color set?

Comment: Thanks for your patience ...... I have added a screenshot from the res file. I am not sure how the shadow is set... The shadow color I have changed tino green to give a better contrast, but it is rendered as transparent..

Comment: Can you add screenshots from the edit page itself? 
Specifically from the border portion in the `...` section

Comment: I have added another screenshot. Does this one help?

Comment: Can you show the Round Rect tab content in the right set of tabs?

Comment: Done so ...... I hope this one helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the runaround but this is a bit of bad news...

I completely forgot that we don't support shadow color in the resource file. It's a part of the developer API for the round rectangle class but it never propagated into the resource file. So it isn't supported by the designer tool or the CSS code.

You have two workarounds you can take:

1. Edit the component and change the borders `RoundRectBorder` instance to include the shadow color. This will mean doing it for every component instance of that type...
2. Use standard CSS shadow tags. This would mean the CSS will generate images instead of a border entry. It will enlarge your resource file and slow down CSS compilation. It might look worse for some cases.

You can also try to submit a PR with the changes to the resource file and additional CSS support. Although that would require a bit of effort.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I will play around with the RoundRectBorder and see if I can make it work. Otherwise, I'll go back to the standard CSS shadow...